# how to extract data by user id(individual) in firebase (seprate both customer_name abc and xyz)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to extract data by user id(individual) in firebase (seprate both customer_name abc and xyz)

```
app-a52d7
    -Ko3c85pJVRRc2rQ5xkS
       customer_dob: "11/12/1996"
       customer_id: "-Ko3c85pJVRRc2rQ5xkS"
       customer_name: "abc"
       customer_phone: "123456789"

    -Ko3udgfeuesdgvbsuhf
       customer_dob: "11/12/1996"
       customer_id: "-Ko3udgfeuesdgvbsuhf"
       customer_name: "xyz"
       customer_phone: "24524424"
```

Comment: Do you have any code that is close to working? Do you at least have a reference to the `app-a52d7` element? Should you try to nest your objects under some common `customers` element?

Comment: I'm done with data retrieving.

Comment: please tell me how I get the value -Ko3c85pJVRRc2rQ5xkS in java code. String id = databaseCustomers.push().getKey(); //this gives me a different value

Comment: @AlokSingh What cricket_007 likely means is that the question is unclear, more words are not likely to make it clearer, and that it's too broad. While it is possible that someone will take a guess at an answer and write the code you need, there's a bigger chance that they'll continue on to another question that is easier to answer. You can improve your chances of getting help by showing the code that you've already tried and where you are stuck. This is known as a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).

Comment: `push().getKey();` will of course give you a different value... That is inserting new data into Firebase. Which documentation are you referring to for simply *retrieving values*?